# Can i get author infos in functions.php for current post viewing?

Tags: wordpress

i would like to get the author nicename in functions.php for the actual content type page that the visitor is viewing. I use that but it does not work :

```
echo get_the_author_meta('user_nicename');
```

Can you show me the correct approach please ?

thanks

Comment: please use `the_author_meta('user_nicename');` and also get it in one variable then echo that variable

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217726/the-author-meta-vs-get-the-author-meta  This will help you

Comment: It might help if you show your code. That way we might be able to tell you what about it is not working!

Answer (score 1):

Use this function get_the_author_meta() - Retrieves the requested data of the author of the current post.

More Info,

Valid values for the $field parameter include:

```
admin_color
aim
comment_shortcuts
description
display_name
first_name
ID
jabber
last_name
nickname
plugins_last_view
plugins_per_page
rich_editing
syntax_highlighting
user_activation_key
user_description
user_email
user_firstname
user_lastname
user_level
user_login
user_nicename
user_pass
user_registered
user_status
user_url
yim
```

[get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) returns the data for use programmatically in PHP. To just display it instead, use [the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/)

If the specified meta field does not exist for this user, an empty string is returned.

**You can get more idea in example:**

Get the email address for user ID 25, and echo it using their display name as the anchor text.

```html
<p>Email the author: <a href="mailto:<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', 25 ); ?>"><?php the_author_meta( 'display_name', 25 ); ?></a></p>
```